# How to make argparse work only with one argument, even if many are passed?

Tags: python, argparse

Structure of my parser:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-s', '--search')
parser.add_argument('-t', '--status' action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.search:
    func(args.search)
if args.status:
    func1()
```

Right now the parser can accept both options, `-s query -t` is valid.
I have two questions:

1. How to take actions on the first argument only if multiple are passed.
   `-s query -t` have to result only

   ```
   if args.search:
       func(args.search)
   ```

   to be done.
2. How to throw an error if multiple args are passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appropriate tool here is a [subparser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands); idiomatic usage is different than what your currently proposed command line looks like.

```
def your_search_function(options):
    pass # do a search here

def your_status_function(options):
    pass # collect status here

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparser(dest='action')

    search_parser = subparsers.add_parser('search')
    search_parser.set_defaults(func=your_search_function)

    status_parser = subparsers.add_parser('status')
    status_parser.set_defaults(func=your_status_function)

    results = parser.parse_args()
    results.func(options=results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Usage then looks like:

```
./yourcommand <global options> search <search options>
```

or

```
./yourcommand <global options> status <status options>
```

...which, since it takes the subcommand to run as an argument rather than an option, does not allow multiple subcommands to be passed, thus mooting the parts of your question only applicable when usage is ambiguous.

---

Global options can be added to `parser` as usual; search-specific options to `search_parser`, and status-specific options to `status_parser`.